# How to Export/Import all CiviCRM data from one website to another one

Tags: database

I am recreating my website on another server. So my big concern is how to move all CRM data to new server/website.
To do separately exporting/importing contacts, membership, activities etc. is not so much accurate way, because there is a possibility of missing something.

Also I can't dump whole database. Is there any possible method, how can I do this??

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Why can't you do a database dump? That is certainly the best approach?

Comment: New website has its separate database, content etc.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to merge some of the old with some of the new.  Please edit your question and describe what databases your current site has, what the new one has and what data from each one you are wanting to keep.

Comment: Both of the websites are built on WordPress. I just want to import all CiviCRM data into new website's database.

Comment: Ok, but do you have one database for both WordPress and Civi, or do they have separate db's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are saying that you have a single database for CMS content on the old site and that you already have new CMS content in the database for the new site. I think you want to move the CiviCRM structure and data. If I have understood that correctly (it would be good if you clarified by editing the question) then you can do the following.

1) split the CMS and CiviCRM databases: KEEP A BACKUP! Create a copy of the combined database by dump, rename the original and then reload). In the original you delete the CiviCRM tables (with e.g. phpMyAdmin) and in the copy, delete the WP tables. You need to edit the civicrm.settings.php to change the name of the CRM database - it will have the same username when created this way. This last bit allows you to keep access to the old CiviCRM so you can check things.

2) on your new site, reinstall CiviCRM using the same version as the old site and the same database details. Now replace the CiviCRM database with the CiviCRM database from the old site. Have a look at the documentation first! https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it would work.

Comment: Hi @MickKahn, any Idea how long this process takes?

Comment: If you mean to actually do the final run, then not much time at all, but you'll want to do various testing etc so that will take quite a bit of time to familiarise yourself. Testing and backup is essential!